# How to install Java 1.1 on 64-bit Windows

Tags: java

I downloaded Java 1.1 from [Oracle Java Archive](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase11-419415.html).

And I tried to install it on Windows 10 (64-bit) ... for research purposes.

However, it failed with the error below.

> ### Unsupported 16-Bit Application
>
> The program or feature "\??\C:\USERS\TEST\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\~EXB0000\setup.exe" cannot start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit versions of Windows. Please contact the software vendor to ask if a 64-bit Windows compatible version is available.

But, **Java 1.1 is a 32-bit application.**
How can I install it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java is a 32-bit application, but the setup launcher is a 16-bit application.
So, I installed it **using ReactOS's InstallShield Engine 3.0 (32-bit application).**

1. Get the Java installer files.

   1. Execute [jdk-1_1_8_010-windows-i586.exe](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase11-419415.html)
   2. When the error dialog is displayed, open `C:\USERS\(User Name)\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\~EXB0000`
      **(Do not click the OK button at this time)**
   3. Copy all files to another folder
   4. Click the ok button
2. Download the tool and execute it.

   1. Download [`Is3Engine.zip` (ReactOS's InstallSheild Engine 3.0)](http://toastytech.com/files/setup.html)
   2. Extract `Is3Engine.zip` (contains`setup32.exe`)
   3. Move `setup32.exe` to the copied Java installers
   4. Execute `setup32.exe`

[image: Java Deveopment Kit 1.1.8_01]

Java 1.1 is now installed.

```
C:\> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.1.8\bin\java.exe -version
java version "1.1.8"
```

Comment: @Robert Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

You should install NTVDMx64. It has Win16 GUI support.

[http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/ntvdmx64.html](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eem36/ntvdmx64.html) (binaries)

https://github.com/leecher1337/ntvdmx64 (source code)